# How do i reset my app after each turn in my game?

Tags: javascript, html

## Magic Eight Ball

```
    <h4>Ask Your Question…</h4>

    <input type="text" id="textInput"><br>
    <div id="btnContainer">
        <button id="btn">Go for it</button>
        <button id="clearBtn">Clear</button>
    </div>
```

How do I reset my app after each turn in my game? I want to stop the `eventListener` from firing the generateAnswer function between each turn. Right now, if you purposely click the 'Go for it' button repeatedly after the first turn, it keeps generating more answers. I would like to stop this from happening so that only one answer appears at a time with each new question entered.

```js
const answers = ['Ask again later', 'Better not tell you now', 'Don’t 
count on it', 'It is certain','Most likely', 'No', 'Outlook not so good', 'Outlook good', 'Signs point to yes', 'Very doubtful','Without a doubt', 'Yes'];

        const textInput = document.querySelector("#textInput");
const clearBtn = document.querySelector("#clearBtn");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
const h4 = document.createElement("h4");


clearBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    h4.remove();
    textInput.value = "";
});
//if text input is populated, run function
function generateAnswer() {
    var ifield = textInput.value;

    if (ifield != '') {
        //if input field is NOT empty, run this code:
        const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length); //generates random answer
        h4.textContent = answers[num];
        h1.append(h4);
    }
}
btn.addEventListener("click", generateAnswer);

if (textInput.length > 0) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", generateAnswer);
} else if (textInput.length === 0){
    btn.removeEventListener("click", generateAnswer);
};
```

Comment: You have to have some way to indicate you are in the middle of a turn (variable `isBusy` set to true while on a turn?) and return from the click handler instead of doing normal processing if the turn isn't over.  When the turn is over and they can click again, clear that variable so the click handler will work as normal again.

Comment: Thank you Jason-can you explain what you mean by  "return from the click handler"?

Comment: Something like `function generateAnswer() { if (isBusy) return;`